# Android: Paging with RemoteMediator keeps loading with load type PREPEND until scroll starts?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I am trying to implement paging using RemoteMediator.

Now, the remote data source is a random dog image API, so the endpoint does not have pagination but instead returns a list of random dog image URLs each request.

The RemoteMediator looks like this:

```
class DogImageRemoteMediator(
    private val database: DogImageDatabase
    private val networkService: DogImageApiService
) : RemoteMediator<Int, DogImageEntity>() {
    
    val dogImageDao = database.dogImageDao()

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, DogImageEntity>
    ): MediatorResult {

        return try {
            val response = networkService.getDogImages(DogImageApiService.BATCH_SIZE)
            database.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    dogImageDao.clearAll()
                }
                dogImageDao.insertAll(response.imageUrls.map { url -> DogImageEntity(url = url) }
                MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = false)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                MediatorResult.Error(e)
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                MediatorResult.Error(e)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
        return InitializeAction.LAUNCH_INITIAL_REFRESH
    }
}
```

Now, the app begins with the initial refresh.

Then, if you do not scroll, RemoteMediator will continue loading with load type `PREPEND`.

When you scroll, RemoteMediator will stop loading with load type `PREPEND`.

The logs look something like this:

```
// ...

PREPEND    // this keeps repeating until scroll
Anchor position: null
Clipped refresh key: null

PREPEND    // scrolled here!
Anchor position: 31
Clipped refresh key: 26
```

Afterwards, when you scroll down, RemoteMediator will load additional data with load type `APPEND`, and the app seems to work as intended.

So, it seems this continuous loading with load type `PREPEND` has something to do with not scrolling when the app initially loads or if the anchor position and clipped refresh key is `null`.

I'm not sure why. I've experimented with the `PagingConfig` values, but can't notice any difference.

The PagingConfig looks like this:

```
PagingConfig(pageSize = 30, initialSize = 10, prefetchDistance = 10)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am still unsure as to why this happens, but I could fix it by adding the code below to the `load` function in the RemoteMediator.

```
if (loadType == LoadType.PREPEND) {
    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
}
```